# Make objects from tests available to the REPL / Poor man's debugging

Tags: clojure

Say, I have a test class like

```
(ns some-tests)

(deftest some-test []
    ...
    (let [x (complicated-object ..)]
        ...))
```

and I run it from a REPL session, using

```
(run-tests 'some-tests)
```

When the test fails, I often need to inspect x.
Often, (complicated-object ..) depends on other objects built before it, so I can not easily create x in my REPL session by hand.

Hence, **I would like a cheap way to make this very x from the actual test available in my REPL session.** I tried wrapping it in an Exception, throwing it and catching it in the REPL, but the unit-test catches all exceptions itself.

Does somebody have an idea how to do this (short of serializing the object to disk)?

PS: I am aware of this hack of introducing breakpoints:
https://coderwall.com/p/xayyvq/break-point-in-clojure,
but this is a new REPL; not my original REPL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I overlooked an obvious way to do this, with an atom.

```
(ns some-tests)

(def tmp (atom nil))

(deftest some-test []
    ...
    (let [x (complicated-object ..)]
        (reset! tmp x)
        ...))
```

After running this test, in the REPL, one can then get the value of x in

```
@some-tests.tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don’t you (def x (complicated ...)) outside the test?

Comment: That is what I now do most of the time. But this is something that comes up over and over again, so I would like a cheap way to get an object that I have in the context of a test into another context (the REPL).  I thought somebody else must have figured this out. Otherwise I guess I have to go over the code of clojure.test ..